# Wordpress pagination not working properly

Tags: php, wordpress

my pagination code:

```
function tevent_pagination() {

// Allowed html 

$allowed_html = [
    "span" => [
        "class" => []
    ],
    "a" => [
        "class" => [],
        "href" => []
    ]
];

// What should be before the page number
$args = [
    'before_page_number' => '<span>',
    'after_page_number' => '</span>'
];
// Printing the pagination
printf("<nav class='pagination'>%s</nav>", wp_kses( paginate_links( $args ), $allowed_html ));}
```

pagination links are correctly displayed, even the content is perfectly display which I click pagination links. but when I click on links the .current class is not updating. I have tried many things but still this issue is not resolving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was resolved by writing wp_reset_query() at the top of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing current page on the args.

```
global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
$args = [
    'before_page_number' => '<span>',
    'after_page_number' => '</span>',
    'format'  => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total'   => $wp_query->max_num_pages
];
echo paginate_links($args);
```

Comment: but get_query_var( "paged" ) is not returnng anything for me.

when I write this: 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
it is also returning 1 even when I am in page 2